# returning the number of times that there are two identical characters

Tags: python-2.7

Define a function immPairs(..) which receives a string and returns the number of times that there are two identical characters one immediately after the other in the string. If there are more than 2 identical characters immediately one after the other, all the immediate pairs should be counted.

For example:

```
immPairs(“abxxab88ef”)
```

should return 2, because of the two immediate pairs “xx” and “88”

```
immPairs(“abxxxab88ef”)
```

should return 3, because of the three immediate pairs “xx”, “xx” and “88”

As an example, the following code fragment:

```
print immPairs("abxxab88ef")
```

should produce the output:
2

This is what I have am I on the right track? I can't figure out what the proper 'if' statement to use if so.

```
def immPairs(st):
   count = 0
   l = list(st)
   for char in l:
     if char == char:
        count = count + 1

  return count

print immPairs("abxxab88ef")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
def immPairs(st):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(st) - 1):
        if st[i] == st[i + 1]:
            count += 1
    return count
```

This iterates over the string by checking each position `i` and `i + 1` to see if they're equal. If they are then you found a pair. This means you only need to check `i` up until just before the last character as the last pair is made up out of the last two characters of the string.

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to lend itself to a one-line solution:

```
In [1]: s = 'abxxxab88ef'
In [2]: sum((s[i]==s[i-1] for i in range(1,len(s)-1)))
Out[2]: 3
```

(Count the number of times a character is the same as its predecessor in a generator which iterates over all but the first character).

The major thing wrong with your posted code is that `char == char` is always `True`. Note also that strings are iterable, so you don't need to convert your `str` into a `list`. To do it your way, you could use `enumerate`:

```
def immPairs(st):
   count = 0
   for i, char in enumerate(st[1:]):
     if char == st[i]:
        count = count + 1

   return count

print immPairs("abxxab88ef")
```

Here, `enumerate` generates the pairs `(0, 'b')`, `(1, 'x')`, etc, so the index `i` is actually the index of the *previous* character in the string.